# PHP If statement is too long, slow down the speed

Tags: php

```
if(strpos($search, "new york") !== FALSE){
    //do something
}
else if(strpos($search, "Los Angeles") !== FALSE){
    //do something
}...//keep going
```

I have use strpos to filter user's input text. If user have enter the **match city**, it will do something

However there are going to have a lots of cities.

If statement will become very long, it will slow down the speed. Is any better way to do this?

Switch statement can break, but I don't know how to use switch + strpos in this case.

Comment: why dont use a select option to choose the city and match just the city or their key?

Comment: too many cities for user to choose, not a good idea

Comment: Use a regex, match for alternatives `(Los Angeles|New York)` and then a `switch`.

Comment: Like Emilio said, I would rethink this a bit. The matches will be harder than you think (different case, misspellings, etc.). How about auto complete?

Comment: you can load the city by state..autocomplete is a good idea

Comment: for a long list of  cities : `auto-complete`.

Comment: Using a `<select>` box, or doing some real-time auto-matching magic, would be the easiest. Surely there is no reason to make it harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Use a dispatch table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should do something like this:

```
$search ="I live in new york but I am moving to los angeles one day.";

$cities_array = array('new york', 'los angeles');
$cities_regex = sprintf('[%s]', implode('|', $cities_array));

if (preg_match_all($cities_regex, $search, $matches)) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($matches);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

The output in my sample will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => new york
            [1] => los angeles
        )

)
```

Or without `print_r` you can just roll through the array and `echo` like so:

```
$search ="I live in new york but I am moving to los angeles one day.";

$cities_array = array('new york', 'los angeles');
$cities_regex = sprintf('[%s]', implode('|', $cities_array));

if (preg_match_all($cities_regex, $search, $matches)) {
  foreach($matches[0] as $matched_key => $matched_value) {
    echo $matched_value . '<br />';
  }
}
```

Now just come up with logic to handle `$matched_value` & there you go.

Answer (score -1):

You can just keep your cities in array and just use the in_array function to check if $search is in the array.

Comment: the problem is different cities will do different things